# Google App engine datastore console shows no entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am having the problem with Datastore Viewer when working with emulator.  http://localhost:8990/_ah/admin/datastore? displays "Datastore has no entities in the Empty namespace. You need to add data programatically before you can use this tool to view and edit it" but when I look into ...\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin file I see it was updated and the entities are there. So for some reasons console doesn't see them. I am using SDK 97.0.0 but the console shows SDK v1.9.27

Comment: Did you try to restart the app/refresh the project?

Comment: I am running my app from Eclipse with Google plugin. I restarted it many times. The local datastore ...\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin is growing in size when I save entities but they don't show up in Datastore Viewer

Comment: No entities of any kind? Do you see any entities at all?

Comment: Nothing. Datastore Viewer in console comes empty. But when in my code I run ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(MyEntety.class).list() (I am using Objectify) it comes up with all entities I created.

Comment: Copy this file somewhere else, then delete it and refresh the project. Restart your app. Was a new, empty file created?

Comment: I did that. It created new files but Datastore Viewer still shows
Entity Kind:
   List Entities
Select different namespace
Show indexes
Datastore has no entities in the Empty namespace. You need to add data programatically before you can use this tool to view and edit it.

Comment: Did you change the project ID?

Comment: No. Does it matter? I got the id when created the project on Google Cloud and want to keep it.
Is it possible that I have older version of Datastore Viewer that can't read new format?

Comment: `local_db.bin` is specific to a project ID. I once changed the project ID, and data viewer came up empty.

Comment: No, I did not change the project ID

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of your storage.bin when running the datastore emulator. Then use that storage path when running the dev_appserver.py:

`dev_appserver.py test.yaml --storage_path=/path/.config/gcloud/emulators/datastore/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin`

Also make sure to connect your appserver to the datastore emulator port.